# CSV import in Excel worksheet to replace 120 columns with 10 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have an external csv file and an xlsb workbook with two sheets. Sheet 1 with 120 columns and sheet 2 with formulas to calculate relevant financial ratios with sheet 1 information.

Out of the 120 columns in sheet 1, I need 10 columns to create sheet 2 with formulas. I have those 10 columns in csv (reduced it with Python df).

I want to use VBA to paste those 10 columns from csv on top of the 120 columns in sheet 1 and delete the 110 unnecessary columns in sheet 1. At the same time, the formulas in sheet 2 should remain and calculate the financial ratios.

My code is pasting those 10 columns on top of the 120 columns and it doesn't get rid of the 110 columns.

```vb
Sub UpdateSource()

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set src = Workbooks.Open("csv file")

With wb
    src.Sheets(1).UsedRange.EntireColumn.Copy
    .Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    With .Sheets(2)
        .Activate
        .Calculate
    End With
End With

src.Close
wb.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior to pasting the new data, you need to delete the old data - then paste the new data.

I suggest first calculating what the last row in wb that holds data is, then using that number to delete that range of data.

```
src.Sheets(1).UsedRange.EntireColumn.Copy

With wb.Sheets(1)

     lastRow= .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

     .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).ClearContents

     .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

End With
```